# Please tell me how to solve star resistance network

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electronics

> Please tell me how to solve star resistance network

[image]

I have tried solving it, but the connection between the crossed resistances is confusing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your diagram was (probably quite deliberately) drawn in an unhelpful way. Recalling that resistances in series sum ($R_{tot} = R_1+R_2$), and for resistors in parallel the reciprocals are summed ($R_{tot}^{-1}  = R_1^{-1}+R_2^{-1}$), I wonder if the following diagram is more helpful?

[image: redrawn circuit]